# Pop to root view controller in app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app that someone logs into and if they launch it after sending it to the background for more than 10 minutes I pop up a nice little "session expired" alert and send them to the root view controller (login page).

Everything works great but I don't know how to pop to the root view controller in my navigation controller stack from the app delegate's applicationWillEnterForeground: method.

I tried saving off the navigationController onto an appDelegate variable but I wonder if the app is in the background for several days, if iOS starts freeing some variables, as I get an error in this method at that time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the navigation controller is your application's root view controller, then you can get it like:

```
UINavigationController *myNavCon = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
```

where `self` is in the app delegate

Comment: typecasting was the key! you are the rockstar

Answer (score 3):

Just to make things more clear one can use following to pop to rootviewcontroller from AppDelegate

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController  *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here self is app delegate.

Comment: Worked liked a charm. For some reason I assumed this would be a pain.