# How to understand this line of Swift code to pop to root view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

I want to write some code to pop from the current view controller back to the root view controller. Confusingly enough, I have found numerous answer regarding this, with all sorts of syntax. (I'm guessing old answers in Objective C or different version of Swift...) Here is the simplest syntax that is currently working for me in my AppDelegate:

```
let navigationViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

[navigationViewController .popToRootViewController(animated: true)]
```

I got this far by viewing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23027260/8887398 
His syntax was slighting different, which I guess is old syntax since it was from 2012, so I had to change it slightly, but it's working with my code above.

**Question:** I don't really understand what's going on in the 2nd line of the code. Sure, I understand it's popping back to the root view controller, but I don't understand the syntax at all. Most confusing is the code is surrounded by a pair of [ ] brackets that I don't understand at all. Next, the popToViewController starts with a dot '.', which is different than the answer I linked. I'm used to using '.' to access properties of an object, but here's it's just used stand alone without anything on the left hand side of it.

This code seems to be functioning properly for me, but which countless versions of syntax and ways to pop back to root view controller I've found across the internet, I have no idea whether what I'm doing is proper or how it works at all. All I know is "it's working right now". Please help me understand this code.

Comment: use of [ ]is the objective approach in swift you can simply write navigationViewController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: That's Objective-C code in the linked answer. You don't need the `[]` around the method call.

Comment: The code you have written is wrong. Square brackets are syntax of objective-c not swift.
If you write something in square brackets in swift, it is considered as an object inside an array.

Comment: Wow, was is just ignoring my space then? Also, any explanation on this syntax, even if it's objective-c would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UINavigationController class has a method inside named as popToRootViewController
which takes a bool parameter named animated. If you pass animated value as true the navigation will happen with animation.

So to call the method in objective c

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController  *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Above in first time we got a pointer to navigationController.
Using that we are calling the popToRootViewControllerAnimated method inside the UINavigationController class with parameter value YES(in Objc YES is for true and NO is for false)

The same thing above can be written in swift as

```
let rootNavController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

rootNavController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Similar to Scenario in OBjc 
the above written syntax is in swift. 
we get the instance of navController an we call the popToRootViewController method()

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's just an array...

You could write: `navigationViewController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

And that would do the same.

If you do :

```
let x = navigationViewController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

`x` will contain an optional array of `UIViewController` of type `[UIViewController]?`

If you do :

```
let x = [navigationViewController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)]
```

`x` will contain an array of with an optional array of `UIViewController` of type `[[UIViewController]?]`

If you do :

```
[navigationViewController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)]
```

The array of array will never be used...

And the space is simply ignored in Swift, for instance you can do :

```
myObject
    .myMethod()
```

It's often used for fluent syntax...

**EDIT**:

The Objective-C call for this method would be:

```
[navigationViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: No, OP tried to copy Objective-C code to Swift without changing the syntax.

Comment: @DávidPásztor In Objective-C there is no dot between the object and the method name in a call in brackets.

Comment: Okay that's making more sense...I didn't realize this is how Objective-C made method calls...that is so awkward.

Comment: @Birdman Ok, if it makes more sense, you can accept the answer ;) !

Comment: @Zaphod yes, OP copied the code incorrectly :) Technically you're right, that would be an array containing a `Void`, but that's not the real answer. The real answer is OP copied Obj-C code without realising that.